# In Excel, how can I make a row of data in a table that has specific text in one cell automatically appear in a table on a seperate sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I download a report with 8 columns of data into a table each week. The amount of data changes each week by row (one week might have 40 rows, the next might have 100 but no more than 150). The data headers would remain the same.

I need to be able to only have all the data in a row where "HOT: Must Cover" appears in column B automatically appear/parse over in an identical table on another sheet. Would I somehow use a VLOOKUP along with =IF?

Example of Table in Sheet 1:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One Option that you have would be to use the filter option in excel then sort them alphabetically on column B. If you really need them on a separate sheet what you can do is copy paste them to the next sheet (since they will all be grouped together from the sorting).

Alternatively you would need to write a macro that reads column B on each line and copies the line if the content is "Hot: Must Cover".

Something along these lines:

```
Dim i as Integer
Dim j as Integer

i = 0
j = 0

Do While Cells(i, 2).value != ""
    if Cells(i, 2).Value == "Hot: Must Cover" Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(j, 0), Cells(j, 7).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(i, 0), Cells(i, 7).Value
        j = j + 1
    End if
    i=i+1
loop
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be difficult to accomplish this with `VLOOKUP` (or any other lookup). Consider this VBA solution:

```
Sub test    
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim j As Integer

    Set ws1 = Worksheets(1)
    Set ws2 = Worksheets(2)
    j = 1

    For i = 2 To (ws1.Range("A1").ListObject.DataBodyRange.Count + 1)
        If ws1.Range("B" & i).Value = "HOT: Must Cover" Then
            ws1.Range("A" & i & ", G" & i).Copy
            ws2.Range("A" & j).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```